# MySQL join on the same field

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

1. messages - with following structure

   id
   sender_id
   receiver_id
   message_text
2. users - with following structure

   id
   nickname

I need to join these two tables so I get result like this:

```
message_id, sender_nickname, receiver_nickname, message_text
```

`sender_id` is always set. The problem is I also need messages where `receiver_id` is 0 so `receiver_id` can't be found in `user` table.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
m.id,
u1.nickname as sender,
u2.nickname as receiver,
m.message_text
from messages as m
left join users as u1 on u1.id = m.sender_id
left join users as u2 on u2.id = m.receiver_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Could look like this:

```
SELECT m.id AS message_id
      ,u1.nickname AS sender_nickname
      ,u2.nickname AS receiver_nickname
      ,m.message_text
FROM   messages m
LEFT   JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = m.sender_id
LEFT   JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = m.receiver_id
```

A `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` guarantees that the left hand table will not be excluded if the right hand table has no matching value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...
FROM messages
INNER JOIN users AS senders ON senders.id = messages.sender_id
LEFT JOIN users AS receivers ON receivers.id = messages.receiver_id
```

And keep the receiver_id column NULL instead of an INT value of 0, when there's no data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a left outer join when joining the messages table to the user table on the receiver_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outerjoin in it

```
select 
m.id as message_id, us.nickname as sender_nickname, ur.nickname as receiver_nickname, m.message_text as message_text
from messages m join users us on us.id = m.sender_id
left outer join users ur.id = m.receiver_id
where m.id = <your message id>
```